# Simple words finder

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, set

We have to find all simple words from a bunch of simple and compound words. For example:
**Input**: chat, ever, snapchat, snap, salesperson, per, person, sales, son, whatsoever, what so.
**Output should be**: chat, ever, snap, per, sales, son, what, so

My sample code:

```
private static String[] find(String[] words) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.out.println();
    ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> r1 = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String s: words){
        alist.add(s);
    }
    Collections.sort(alist,new Comparator<String>() {

        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

            return o1.length()-o2.length();
        }
    });
    //System.out.println(alist.toString());


    int count= 0;
    for(int i=0;i<alist.size();i++){
        String check = alist.get(i);
        r1.add(check);
        for(int j=i+1;j<alist.size();j++){

            String temp = alist.get(j);
            //System.out.println(check+" "+temp);
            if(temp.contains(check) ){

                alist.remove(temp);

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(r1.toString());
    String res[] = new String[r1.size()];
    for(String i:words){
        if(r1.contains(i)){
            res[count++] = i;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

I am unable to get a solution with the above code. Any suggestions or ideas

compound word = concatenation of two or more words;rest all words are considered as simple words
We have to remove all the compound words

Comment: OK, what now; do you have a question?

Comment: What is the observed behavior?

Comment: I am unable to get Son as so is already added to my list and son is getting removed @atri

Comment: What is the definition of simple words in this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm

1. Read the input into a set of Strings i.e. `Set<String> input`
2. Create a empty set for simple words i.e. `Set<String> simpleWords`
3. Create a empty set for compound words i.e. `Set<String> compoundWords`
4. Iterate over `input`. For each `element`

   1. Let length of `element` be `elemLength`
   2. Create a set `Set<String> inputs` of all Strings from the set `input` (excluding `element`) for which the below is true

      1. Length less than `element`
      2. Not present in `compundWords`
   3. Create set of all permutations of `inputs`(by concatenating) with max length = `elemLength` i.e. `Set<String> currentPermutations`
   4. See if any of `currentPermutations` is = `element`

      1. If yes, add `element` into `compoundWords`
      2. If no, continue with iteration
5. After the iteration is done place all Strings from `input` which are not present in `compoundWords` into `simpleWords`

That is your answer.

Before you start writing code decide the logic that you are going to use. Use descriptive variable names and you are basically done.

The reason your logic is not working has to do with the way you are checking `temp.contains(check)`. This is checking for substring not a compound word as per your definition.

Comment: I didn't understand your 3rd point about concatenations, could you pleas elaborate @aseembansal

Comment: @tejachilled Suppose you have "snapchat, snap, chat". You are iterating with element = snapchat. Then inputs will have "snap, chat". Now you create concatentations - snapchat, chatsnap. Then you check whether element is one of them or not.

Comment: @tejachilled If any answer actually answers your question then you should accept it.

Comment: If you could write a working code or provide me a clear solution, I will def accept it. @aseembansal